# How can I make LaTeX fail on a missing cross-reference?

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a way to make `\ref` and `\pageref` fail instead of printing `??` if the `.aux` file doesn't have any page number for the requested label?

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or any other cross-referencing package?

Comment: ...note that this will be a useless feature, since the introduction of any new (previously non-existent) `\label`-and-`\ref` will fail; you need at least one compilation in order for the `\label` to have a valid reference/page number.

Comment: @Werner I am aware of this, but it will not be a useless feature because I will only enable it on the second run in my build process.

Answer (score 4):

The macro responsible for printing **`??`** a warning when you `\ref`erence a non-existent `\label` is `\@setref`:

```
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}
```

You can just change the use of `\@latex@warning` to `\@latex@error` (accommodating for `\@latex@error` needing *two* arguments rather than `\@latex@warning`'s *one*):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@setref}{\@latex@warning}{\@latex@error}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setref}{\else}{\relax\else}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\label{sec:section1}
See section~\ref{sec:section1}.% Succeeds ...
                               % ... IF you have already compiled with \label{sec:section1}
See section~\ref{sec:section2}.% Fails

\end{document}
```

The use of this feature seems useless... if we assume the use-case is that you have an existing document that has some undefined `\ref`erences that you want to identify, you'll "activate" this redefinition and compile. Now, somewhere mid-document your compilation fails (assuming again you are not running LaTeX in `nonstopmode`) and compilation stops. All references following this fail will be undefined in subsequent compilations (since their `\label`s haven't been written to the `.aux`), which will again fail. So you'll have to constantly active/de-active this "feature" and perform multiple compilations after every failure.

A better option would be to process your `.log` and identify the undefined `\ref`erences using a regular text search.

Comment: I am building with the Nix package manager. All builds will be from a fresh state; there will be no "subsequent compilations"

Comment: Then I'm not sure how you expect this to work in light of Werner's next to last paragraph.  A fresh state without an aux file will most likely come across missing references.

Comment: from a fresh state, two things happen: first I generate the aux files, then I run with ref failures enabled

Comment: I don't find it useless to have some command `\finalcompilation` which turns some warnings which shouldn't occur in the last compilation into errors.